# Не работает выпадающий список. Ошибка "Нет элемента ViewData типа "IEnumerable <SelectListItem>", который имеет ключ *имя*". C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Контроллер:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Books> authors;
        using (Model1 db = new Model1())
        {
            authors = db.Books.ToList();
            SelectList author = new SelectList(db.Authors, "Id", "FirstName", db.Authors.Select(model => model.Id));
            ViewBag.AuthorId = author;
        }
        return View(authors);




    }
```

Представление:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.AuthorId as SelectList)
```

Модель:

```
    public partial class Books
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    public int AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int? Pages { get; set; }
    public int? Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }


}
```

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Проверял код, пишу все правильно, но при попытке создать поле с названием книги, цены, и кол-ва листов - выходит эта ошибка "Нет элемента ViewData типа "IEnumerable ", который имеет ключ *имя*". Уже не знаю в чем дело, и как исправить.

Пытался найти решение на форумах, создавал список по гайдам и статьям, но все равно один и тот же результат.

Причем, если использовать обычный EditorFor, и ввести Id созданного автора - всё работает. Что я делаю не так? Из-за чего возникает ошибка, и как её исправить?

Заранее, большое спасибо.